# Threejs is it possible update or overwrite a geometry?

Tags: 3d, three.js

I need to do something like this. (this is just a sample code just to show you the logic)

```
var counter = 0;
// save original geometry
var geometry_clone = box.geometry.clone();
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    //restore original geometry
    box.geometry = geometry_clone;
    modifier.set(direction, axis, counter ).modify( box.geometry );
    counter = counter + .001;
    render();
}
```

I am using a bend modifier to animate bending but I need to revert to original state of geometry each time I use bend modifier. Is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question.

```
var counter = 0;

// save original geometry
var saved_clone = box.geometry.clone();
var geometry_clone;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

    box.geometry.dispose();
    //clone original geometry so it remains intact
    geometry_clone = saved_clone.clone();
    box.geometry = geometry_clone;
    modifier.set(direction, axis, counter ).modify( box.geometry );
    counter = counter + .001;
    render();
}
```

The trick was to clone and assign 2 times since you're disposing the original geometry. I did it so I can revert the original geometry.

My animation went smoothly.